# set max-height of flexbox sidebar to never exceed the other box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've a flex layout with two columns: one `sidebar`, one `content`.

I need a way to make so the sidebar height is never higher than the height of the box-content.

My CSS is:

```
.layout {
  display: flex;
}
.sidebar {
}
.content {
  flex: 1;
}
```

http://codepen.io/FezVrasta/pen/WvwZxo

How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

http://dcousineau.com/blog/2011/07/14/flex-box-prevent-children-from-stretching/

You have to put a `div` inside the `sidebar` and set its `height` to `0`, it will make the trick.